# gitlab markdown delete file

Tags: file, gitlab

I use GitLab CE 9.5.3 and I've added a file as attachment to a repository, but when I've deleted the file from the gitlab console the file has not been deleted from the file system.

Have you got any suggestions on how to fix it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reflect the changes made on the web to your file system, you have to perform a `git pull` from your system.